# Jquery Ui sortable items option select just first item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

In my below code just the first `#sort-item` is sortable, others not. How can I solve it?

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
   items:"#sort-item"
});
```

Html;

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li id="sort-item"></li>
    <li id="sort-item"></li>
    <li id="sort-item"></li>
    <li id="sort-item"></li>
    <li id="sort-item"></li>
</ul>
```

Edit:
I try;

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
   items:"> #sort-item"
});
```

But steal not working

jsFiddle;
https://jsfiddle.net/seamqykd/1/

Comment: Can you please generate Example Like: https://jsfiddle.net/a70qkb95/

Comment: items:"#sort-item" this will work only on first record, You need to give class instead of ID("#sort-item").

Comment: @KHIMAJIVALUKIYA I use class and solver thank you for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign multiple items the same ID (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp)

Use a class to select the items:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="sort-item"></li>
    <li class="sort-item"></li>
    <li class="sort-item"></li>
    <li class="sort-item"></li>
    <li class="sort-item"></li>
</ul>

$('#sortable').sortable({
  items:".sort-item"
});
```

or even better, use the element

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
  items:"li"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First using id in multiple element is an html Sementic Error, Id's are used to be in one and only one html element ,

And here that's what causes the issue, just replace in the html your `id` by a `class` name and in your js code replace `#sort-item` by `.sort-item`  see below working snippet :

```js
$('#sortable').sortable({
  items:".sort-item"
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="sort-item">aaa</li>
    <li class="sort-item">bbb</li>
    <li class="sort-item">ccc</li>
    <li class="sort-item">ddd</li>
    <li class="sort-item">eee</li>
</ul>
```